# Backward-counting day display in php

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

I would like to show the number of days missing for a specific date.  In other words, I want to display something like:

> X days to go for the great event

using PHP and the server time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php

    $event_date = '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
    $event_time = strtotime($event_date);
    $diff = $event_time - time();
    echo floor($diff/(24*60*60)).' days to go for the great event';

?>
```

**Note**: I'm totally side stepping any *timezone* considerations, so, be sure you read up on timezone issues associated with using the PHP `datetime` functions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ceil? If there are 12 hours until midnight of the day of the "great event", most people would consider that a day away.

Comment: X = full days until event, if he wanted to make it a little more complicated, he could set a conditional to detect when less than a day remains and echo out a different string.

Answer (score 3):

jakemcgraw's answer would have my vote, had I 15 rep. :)

You might want to use mktime() instead of strtotime(), though.